# how to stop an EC2 instance after checking the memory utilization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to stop my EC2 instances if the memory utilization is more than x% from my Lambda function(python) , is their any possibility to check the memory utilization of an EC2 instance

Comment: if you dont want to use the lambda function then you can use Auto Scaling groups and its policies to terminate or launch instances based on memory utilization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For EC2 by default it will only have the [host level metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html) be accessible, this includes CPU, Disk Performance and Network Performance but does not include other metrics such as Memory Utilization.

For this you will need to push a custom metric from the EC2 instance into AWS, this can be performed by installing the [CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html).

Once you have the memory metric being pushed into CloudWatch you can create an alarm that will trigger on a specific threshold being exceeded, allowing you to trigger an SNS topic. This can have a Lambda [subscribe](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-subscribe-sns-topic-same-account/) to the topic to be triggered under the condition.

Comment: Thanks , we are going with CPU utilization instead of Memory as we have to shutsown all instances which are running not the single instace .  Can you also check my other question which is nearly same as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64388033/how-to-get-the-sagemaker-instance-cpu-utilization

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [CloudWatch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) on the EC2 instances, if it's not there already. Then the memory usage will be a metric in CloudWatch that your Lambda function can query.