# How to get the Sagemaker instance CPU utilization

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I would Like to get the CPU utilization of a SageMaker Notebook to Monitor the load and if the load is less than for x% for a hour ,I will stop the instance using Lambda(python) .

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatch.html